# Windows tool to decode HTML entities in a file

Tags: javascript, windows, batch-file, command-line

Is there a command line/batch script tool for Windows that can be used to decode HTML entitles like `&nbsp;`, `&weierp;`, and `&#8240;` to readable UTF-8 text?

I found this web tool (https://mothereff.in/html-entities) that uses javascript that can do just this but I need this done from a Windows batch file. I know of the amazing JREPL.bat utility which incorporates javascript into windows command shell to make regex replacements in files. I just can't find a similar tool for HTML entities conversion.

Edit: To the bright coders out there, I hope you can write a batch tool that can perform HTML entities decoding/encoding to help me and the future readers looking for the same solution. Here are Github pages I think can be of use: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he https://github.com/mathiasbynens/mothereff.in/tree/master/html-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need extensive applications (like JREPL.bat or my own [FindRepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697)) or complicated programs in order to perform a replacement as simple as this one. The small Batch file below is an example that performs a replacement of 3 HTML entities:

```
@set @a=0 // & cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < input.txt & goto :EOF

var rep = new Array();
rep["&#xA9;"]   = "\u00A9";
rep["&#xD306;"] = "\uD306";
rep["&#x2603;"] = "\u2603";

var f = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile("output.txt", true, true);
f.Write(WScript.Stdin.ReadAll().replace(/&#xA9;|&#xD306;|&#x2603;/g,function (A) {return rep[A]}));
f.Close();
```

input.txt:

```
Foo &#xA9; bar &#xD306; baz &#x2603; qux
```

output.txt:

```
Foo © bar 팆 baz ☃ qux
```

You only need to add as many character equivalences as you want to convert...

Comment: I have no idea how to put this to use. Could you tell me how I can call it from a Windows batch file?

Comment: Just copy the code into a file with .BAT extension, for example: `convert.bat`; then, invoke it from the command prompt by typing its name: `C:\Your\path> convert.bat`. You may modify the `input.txt` and `output.txt` file names in the code by another ones, or use parameters instead. To call this Batch file from another one, use CALL command: `call convert.bat`

Comment: If it isn't too much to ask, could you write the opposite script that can encode everything _except_ the **0-127 range ASCII characters** to HTML entities using a js code like this: `function a(b) { var c= ''; for(i=0; i<b.length; i++){ if(b.charCodeAt(i)>127){ c += '&#' + b.charCodeAt(i) + ';'; }else{ c += b.charAt(i); } } document.forms.conversionForm.outputText.value = c; }`? I think using the concept, you don't have to enumerate the character arrays as there are literally thousands of unicode characters. I found it on http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php

Comment: I was going to edit my message to clarify that I need the conversion going to HTML _**numeric**_ entities but apparently, editing 5 minute+ old messages is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to incorporate JScript into a batch file, so you could easily write your own custom hybrid JScript/batch script that incorporates the he.js found at https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he.

But it is even simpler to use the [JREPL.BAT tool](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) that you already mentioned. You can use the `/JLIB` option to load the he.js code, thus making all of the he (html-entities) functionality accessible to JREPL.

Here is a trivial example that decodes test.txt, overwriting the original file.

```
jrepl "^.*" "he.decode($0)" /jlib "he.js" /f test.txt /o -
```

This isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it is probably plenty fast enough, and it sure is convenient.

Here is another example that encodes every character in test.txt (including newlines), writing the result to out.txt

```
jrepl "^[\s\S]*" "he.encode($0,{encodeEverything:true})" /m /j /jlib he\he.js /f test.txt /o out.txt
```

You should study all the documentation for both he and JREPL to discover all the possibilities.

The regex portion in the examples might seem to be more of a hindrance then help. But it is easy to envision how it might be useful to selectively encode only portions of your input text. Or you could use the JREPL /T option to use different encoding options for different sections of text.

Comment: Hi @dbenham! If it isn't too much to ask, could you write the opposite windows batch/jscript hybrid that can encode everything _except_ the **0-127 range ASCII characters** to numeric HTML entities using a js code like this: `function a(b) { var c= ''; for(i=0; i<b.length; i++){ if(b.charCodeAt(i)>127){ c += '&#' + b.charCodeAt(i) + ';'; }else{ c += b.charAt(i); } } document.forms.conversionForm.outputText.value = c; }`? I found it on http://unicodetools.com/unicode/convert-to-html.php It looks very straightforward. And I know a coding task like this is trivial for you. Thank you in advance!